# Catching HTTP substatuscode in JQuery Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, iis

Is there a way to read the HTTP-substatus of the server's response to a jQuery `ajax()` call ?

As mentioned here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR, the main HTTP status is found in the `status` attribute on the jqXHR, returned in the `error` callback. However, it has no attribute for the substatus.

Context : I'm working with file-uploads to IIS. IIS returns a 404 Status with substatus 13 when the file is too large, which I want to catch in the front-end to display the correct message to the user.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I guess this substatus code info is IIS specific for logging and custom error page displaying purpose, and is not sent to the client. Anyway you may be able to set-up a dynamic custom error page for 404.13 errors in IIS, returning a json error with a friendly message when json (I guess) content-type is asked by the client.

Comment: This could be true indeed. I will look into it. The proposed solution for a custom errorpage sounds great. Thanks

Comment: @jbl, as you suggested, indeed, the substatus code is IIS specific. In the meanwhile, we've decided to go for chunking of the uploads, so IIS's maximum file size will not be reached. Thanks !